# Solution to set the destination location of a python web service that does ftp

Tags: python, python-2.7

### Background: (script works fine)

I have created a script to in python to read a file location from a database, and then retrieve the file, through FTP. This will become a web service to be used by multiple applications.

I started using `urlretrieve`, which was fine if the protocol was 1.0 and not 1.1. (urlretrieve is not closing the connection)

I now am using ftplib to make the connection.

### Problem:

How do i set the destination location for the file, when it is running as a web service?

If the script is running on a server the call `os.chdir()` doesn't have access to the workstation of the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FTP.cwd(pathname)` as shown in the example [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) and described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.cwd).

Comment: This will change the dir on the web server. I need to be able to set the destiniation of the consuming desktop, More like what urlretrieve does.